# CiviCRM backup query

Tags: database, settings, backups

I want to make a weekly/fortnight backup of CiviCRM running on Wordpress. Two things I need to do:

1. Backup on same machine
2. Replicate the database on another machine.

Looking for simple steps to achieve both

OS : Windows , Separate databases for Wordpress and CiviCRM

Answer (score 1):

This question is impossible to answer definitively without knowing more about, say, your operating system, whether you have command line access, whether your WP and Civi databases are separate or one, etc.  I'll answer for what works for me.

On a Linux machine, I would use `backupninja` to first back up MySQL using `mysqldump`.  My [backupninja configurations](https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/backupninja_configs) are public.

Second, I configure a backupninja job using `rsync`, `rdiff-backup`, or `borgbackup` to back up the WordPress root (e.g. `/var/www/mysite`) along with the MySQL dump.  All three of those utilities can back up either locally or remotely.

If you prefer shell scripts to backupninja, AGH Strategies posts their [backup script](https://github.com/agh1/backupscripts) on Github.

Comment: edited. not a linux user :( !

Comment: @ParthibarajRajasekar This is a sysadmin question and not a CiviCRM question.  You may want to either a) ask in chat.civicrm.org, or b) search Stack Exchange and/or Google for Windows backup solutions that include MySQL databases.  If you back up the MySQL dump plus the WordPress root folder and all subfolders, you should be good.